# Store new files in IMAP folders

Tags: email, imap

Is it possible to create a new file (simple text file) and store it within an IMAP folder?

So e.g. my program analyzes the mails and wants to store a file with statistics in an IMAP folder, so it's stored on the server and not locally so that you can get the information through all platforms. Of course this may be a misuse of these folders (normally they are supposed to store emails), but exists a functionality in IMAP that lets me upload whatever I want to specific folders on the server?

Comment: You could embed your file in a mime message, eg, an attachment, and APPEND it to a folder.

Comment: While reading RFC 3502 I found "append" and I thought it could solve my problem. I'm already implementing it, thanks for your help. But maybe arnt's solution will be better if the server support it.

Comment: Appending a magic message is a common hack for such things. It loses when someone comes along and moves or deletes the magic message using another client. I've even heard of a spam filter training itself to delete it. But perhaps that isn't a concern in your case.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [METADATA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5464) extension. Not very widely supported, but perhaps your goal is a server that happens to support it.

The people who voted your question down should do penance by reading RFC5464.

Comment: This sounds great, after reading the RFC 5464 I think this is what I searched for, thank you. I have to look, if the server support it.